# IDEA: Gradle не "активируется" при клонировании из GIT

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

Клонировал проект из GIT. В проекте уже присутствует gradle, но зависимости почему-то не подсвечиваются. Хотя, проект отображается во вкладке, даже собирается war, но не собирается war:exploded.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, как вернуть gradle нормальный вид? С этой проблемой я сталкиваюсь при клонировании каждого проекта.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, выяснилось, что всему виной `gradle-wrapper`, которого не было в проекте. Я скопировал в проект wrapper из другого проекта и всё заработало.

Для этого потребовалось удалить проект `gradle` из вертикальной вкладки в правой части IDEA и добавить заново, указав, что Вы будете пользоваться `wrapper`-ом (который нужно добавить заранее).

Также, может быть такое, что существующий `wrapper` не работает корректно. В таком случае, также, можно скопировать рабочий `wrapper` со всей папкой `gradle` из другого проекта.